# Object is exist with value, but when access the property returned undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

i find weird things. I have AuthService which saves authentication needs of my apps, included authentication token.

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public modalCtrl:ModalController,public auth: AuthService) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log(this.auth)
    console.log(this.auth.loggedIn)
    if(this.auth.loggedIn){
      console.log(this.auth);
      this.navCtrl.push("TabsPage");
    }    
  }
}
```

when i call

```
console.log(this.auth)
```

it returned [authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbJzn.png)
buth when i call

```
console.log(this.auth.loggedIn)
```

it return null

this my auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, NgZone, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

// Import AUTH_CONFIG, Auth0Cordova, and auth0.js
import { AUTH_CONFIG } from './auth.config';
import Auth0Cordova from '@auth0/cordova';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  Auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth(AUTH_CONFIG);
  Client = new Auth0Cordova(AUTH_CONFIG);
  accessToken: string;
  user: any;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  loading = true;

  constructor(
    public zone: NgZone,
    private storage: Storage
  ) {
    this.storage.get('profile').then(user => this.user = user);
    this.storage.get('access_token').then(token => this.accessToken = token);
    this.storage.get('expires_at').then(exp => {
      this.loggedIn = Date.now() < JSON.parse(exp);
      this.loading = false;
    });

  }

  login() {
    this.loading = true;
    const options = {
      scope: 'openid profile offline_access'
    };
    // Authorize login request with Auth0: open login page and get auth results
    this.Client.authorize(options, (err, authResult) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      // Set access token
      this.storage.set('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
      this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
      // Set access token expiration
      const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
      this.storage.set('expires_at', expiresAt);
      // Set logged in
      this.loading = false;
      this.loggedIn = true;
      // Fetch user's profile info
      this.Auth0.client.userInfo(this.accessToken, (err, profile) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        this.storage.set('profile', profile).then(val =>
          this.zone.run(() => this.user = profile)
        );
      });
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.storage.remove('profile');
    this.storage.remove('access_token');
    this.storage.remove('expires_at');
    this.accessToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }

  isLoggedIn() :boolean{
    return this.loggedIn;
  }
}
```

i'm using ionic3 and auth0 authentication, previously i think that was my fault to not use public identifier on my property. but when i change the property to public, or create getter method that returned the property it still not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to when the chrome console evaluates the object. If you open the object in your console, you'll see a tiny blue info icon. This will say:

> Value was evaluated just now

Basically what happens is that the object content changed between the time you logged it, and the time you opened it in your console.

The login action is asynchronous, which means that the `loggedIn` property on the auth object will be set after the `ionViewDidLoad` is called. Perhaps a good thing would be to set the auth inside an [`APP_INITIALIZER`](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) provider, or have some Observable on your auth on which you can listen for auth changes

Comment: if i set auth in app_initilzer. do i still need observable?

Comment: @rezaridwansyah I think you do, for instance when the auth token expires and the user is still logged in

Answer (score 0):

1.you have colling this.loggedIn before assign so that it's undefined.
in your case write console.log(this.auth.loggedIn) after login. please check that scenario.

2.for now, assign some value for loggedIn variable then print it will print a value

**loggedIn: boolean;** =>  **loggedIn: boolean=false;** 
 then print a value it will work

in some other component

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.auth.loggedIn)
  }
```

Comment: in auth.service.ts i use isLoggedIn() :boolean{
    return this.loggedIn;
  } and still returning undefined